# Delphi. New и dispose вместо GetMem и FreeMem

Tags: delphi, утечка-памяти

Получаю пакеты по сети. Я знаю, что размер пакета не будет больше 2000 байт.
Так как получение пакета в одном потоке, а обработка в другом, то мне нужно передать **копию buf** через TList. Соответственно, создаю буфер в одном потоке, а уничтожаю в другом.

Раньше использовал следующую связку

```
type
tbuf = array [0..1999] of byte;
pbuf = ^tbuf;
...
getmem(buf, 2000);
...
freemem(buf, 2000);
```

---

Теперь нужно

```
type
pbuf = ^TidBytes; //динамический массив байт

...
new(buf);
...
dispose(buf);
```

---

Как машина поймет, сколько нужно освободить, ведь размер неизвестен заранее?
может сначала нужно сделать

```
setlength(buf,0);
```

Comment: Есть *скрытая* информация, где хранится размер блока. freemem или dispose всегда знают сколько освободить.

Comment: Есть. Но передавать его размер, в другой поток накладно по ресурсам. и freemem не знает, сколько освободить

Comment: Вы передаёте указатель верно? *Скрытая* информация о размере функция получает именно через переданный указатель. Если копнуть глубже то... о... функция freemem и dispose делает блокировку потоков при освобождении кучи. Так что проблема многозадачности уже давно тут решена. Если бы этого не было, было бы куча топиков в сети с проблемой "я освободил память, а другой поток это не видит" с готовым соллюшином, но этого нету. К счастью операции с памятью работают без глюков.

Comment: Указатель передаю. Только dispose знает размер, если тип простой или указан явно. А динамический массив, на то и динамический, что не определишь

Comment: Определишь. Для вас это *скрытая* информация. Если вам интересно как её раскрыть - то переформулируйте вопрос. Определённая последовательность вычислений с **указателем** позволяет **определить** размер блока.

Comment: Т.е. я могу написать dispose(buf) и спать спокойно? А как раскрыть скрытую информацию очень интересно

Comment: http://delphimaster.net/view/1-1150732226 это для 32-битной версии. Для 64 нужно искать, или -8 пробовать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, у меня как раз 64. Пробовать -8, а также под конкретные платформы не айс. У меня это должно работать везде. По указанной вами ссылки, ответ - не понятно

Comment: Если в Dispose передавать переменную, у которой тип - указатель на динамический массив. то высвобождение должно пройти правильно. Если передавать нетипизированный указатель (просто pointer) - то высвободится только он, а не содержимое массива. Воспользуйтесь `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=True` и увидите, есть ли утечки.

Comment: А чем вас не устроил старый вариант?

Comment: стал использовать indy10 вместо самостийного чтения socketa, так как нужен в дальнейшем linux, а в indy само будет компилиться

Comment: Хорошо, а почему теперь нельзя сделать `getmem(buf, 2000)` как раньше?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci , потому что тип теперь динамический, да и вообще можно вызывать просто freemem как сказал nick_n_a , а менеджер памяти сам разберется что почем

Comment: Почему динамический? Какой хочу, такой и объявляю. Причем здесь INDY и его типы? Получили от него байты, скопировали в свой **статический** массив функцией CopyMemory и радуемся жизни. Делаете проблему из ничего.

Comment: а почему copymemory? может move или bytestoraw? что быстрее?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, писать второй аргумент у `FreeMem` не нужно. Т.е. должно быть так:

```
GetMem(Buf, 2000);
try
  // что-то делаем
finally
  FreeMem(Buf);
end;
```

Менеджер памяти Delphi (код, который реализует `GetMem`/`FreeMem`) просто запоминает размер выделенного блока в своих служебных структурах. Где и как он это делает - вам знать не требуется, это зависит от конкретной реализации менеджера памяти, которая может меняться. Вам достаточно знать, что `FreeMem` всегда корректно освободит память, выделенную ранее вызовом `GetMem`, `AllocMem` (а также - `New`, при условии, что финализацию вы сделаете сами) - разумеется, в предположении, что в `FreeMem` вы передаёте ровно тот же указатель, что вам вернула `GetMem`, `AllocMem` или `New`. Вам не нужно специально хранить размер выделенной области (если только этот размер не нужен вам для ваших личных целей).

Во-вторых, `TIdBytes` является динамическим массивом, т.е. это уже динамически выделяемая память в куче, аналог "старого" `Buf`. Не нужно делать на него указатель: это получается "указатель на указатель", лишний уровень косвенности. Передавайте просто переменную `TIdBytes`. Т.е. было:

```
procedure DoSomething(Buf: Pointer);
begin
  // ...
end;

var
  Buf: Pointer;
begin
  GetMem(Buf, 2000);
  try
    DoSomething(Buf);
  finally
    FreeMem(Buf);
  end;
end;
```

Стало:

```
procedure DoSomething(Buf: TIdBytes);
begin
  // ...
end;

var
  Buf: TIdBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Buf, 2000);
  DoSomething(Buf);
  // Необязательно: Finalize(Buf);
end;
```

Этот код работает в точности так же, как и предыдущий: данные Buf передаются по ссылке. Если вам нужна именно копия данных (не очень понятно, как вы хотели решить этот вопрос переходом к `TIdBytes` и/или использованием "указателя на указатель") - просто скопируйте массив:

```
var
  Buf: TIdBytes;
  Buf2: TIdBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Buf, 2000);
  // Как-то заполняем Buf

  // Делаем копию
  Buf2 := Copy(Buf); // это стандартная функция Copy(что, индекс, длина), 
  // где второй и третий параметр опущены

  // Передаём копию:
  DoSomething(Buf2);
end;
```

> Как машина поймет, сколько нужно освободить, ведь размер неизвестен заранее?

`Dispose` - это "волшебная" функция компилятора. У неё, на самом деле, два параметра. Первый передаёте вы: это указатель на блок памяти. Второй скрытно передаёт компилятор: это указатель на информацию о типе переменной. Соответственно, в информации типа указано, что лежит в переменной, так что функция `Dispose` будет знать как корректно освободить память. В данном случае там будет сказано: "в переменной лежит динамический массив", так что `Dispose` сделает ему `SetLength` в 0. Ну и `SetLength`, соответственно, знает размер массива, чтобы корректно его освободить.

P.S. Кстати, `Dispose` эквивалентен вызову `Finalize` + `FreeMem`.

Answer (score 0):

Итого.
В процедуре приема пакетов

```
Procedure udpSrvRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  sizePacket: LongInt;
  FBuffer: PidBytes;
  FQ: TQueue<PidBytes>;
begin
      sizePacket := Length(AData);
    if sizePacket = 0 then
    else
    begin
      new(FBuffer);
      SetLength(FBuffer^, sizePacket);
      CopyTIdBytes(AData, 0, FBuffer^, 0 , sizePacket);
      FQ.Enqueue(ABuffer); 
    end;
end;
```

При разборе

```
var
  Pack: PidBytes;
if FQ.Count > 0  then
begin
  Pack:= FQ.Dequeue;
  {...работа с Pack}
  Dispose(Pack);
End;
```

А как не делать копию? Как можно получить данные пакета, если передал ссылку на него, а потом туда же записал новые данные?
А так работает.